# pdf viewer bookmarks/table of contents has wrong page numbers

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

When I generate the PDF from my main tex file, I have the correct page numbers shown in the Table of Contents, and the correct sections listed in the PDF Viewer's sidebar pane, but the PDF Viewer's sidebar shows all the sections as having page number 1.

I suspect this may be because I'm putting all my sections in subfiles. How can I get the PDF Viewer's sidebar to show the correct page numbers?

I'm using `bookmark` and `hyperref`.

Example:

Main.tex

```latex
\documentclass[legal,12pt,twoside,draft]{memoir}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % If utf8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English please
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % Less badboxes

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\medievalpage
\title{Proof Of Concept}
\author{}
\date{}

\OnehalfSpacing 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents{}

\subfile{contents/ch_01.tex}
\subfile{contents/ch_02.tex}
\subfile{contents/ch_03.tex}


\end{document}
```

example subfile:

```latex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

in the pdf viewer, this looks like:
[image]

Comment: hyperref doesn't add page numbers to the bookmarks. Which viewer do you use? And did you really try your example (e.g. the lipsum package is missing so you should get an error).